# Getting Operation is not allowed when the object is closed when calling SQL Server Stored Procedure in ASP Classic

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

In my asp classic code I want to call a stored procedure. However if I try, I get

```
Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.
```

ASP code:

```
dim soc
dim sql
dim dbConn
dim adRsTKIDEmpNum


set soc = Request.QueryString("id_list")


set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set adRsTKIDEmpNum = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

dbConn.Open Application("System_ConnectionString")



sql = "sp_getEmployeeDetail '2411, 3468'"
adRsTKIDEmpNum.Open sql, dbConn, 1

do while not adRsTKIDEmpNum.EOF


loop

Response.write sql
```

when I call `do while not adRsTKIDEmpNum.EOF`, I get the error.

stored procedure

```
Alter Procedure dbo.sp_getEmployeeDetail
    @IDList varchar (max)
As

Declare @EmployeeDetail table(ID int,Employee_Number int)

insert into @EmployeeDetail(ID, Employee_Number) 
select A.Item, B.employee_number from people.dbo.udf_Split(@IDList, ',') A
left join people.dbo.employee B on A.Item=B.ID

select * from @EmployeeDetail

GO
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should avoid the sp_ prefix in your procedure names. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix Also, most splitters I have seen out there are horribly inefficient. You might take a peek at this to see if your splitter measures up. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: The other issue I see here is that you have not parameterized your sql and are directly executing a query string value. This is an open invitation for bobby tables to come visit.

Comment: Is that whats casing the error?

Comment: Put the loop inside a conditional block that checks to see if the recordset object is actually open.

Comment: You have to put line of code in Stored Proc right after AS  : SET NOCOUNT ON

Comment: Or You'll get multirecordset - 1st - how many records inserted, 2nd - needed output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter Procedure dbo.sp_getEmployeeDetail
    @IDList varchar (max)
As
SET NOCOUNT ON
Declare @EmployeeDetail table(ID int,Employee_Number int)

insert into @EmployeeDetail(ID, Employee_Number) 
select A.Item, B.employee_number from people.dbo.udf_Split(@IDList, ',') A
left join people.dbo.employee B on A.Item=B.ID

select * from @EmployeeDetail

GO
```